# Phone number regex should strictly allow 10 characters if starting with 02/03/04/07/08

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

The below expression is being used to accept Australian phone numbers.
I need to change the expression as to strictly accept total 10 digits (without spaces) if the number starts with 02/03/04/07/08.

```
^\({0,1}((0|\+61)\s?(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}\){0,1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{3}$
```

It does accept 10 digits if the number is entered like 03 11 11 1 111, but without spaces 8 digit number is accepted too.

Comment: Your regex is complicated.  It would be helpful to show a bunch of sample input Australian phone numbers, to show the various formats.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the use the following regex with alternation:

```
^ *(?:0 *[23478](?: *\d){8}|[1-9](?: *\d)*|0 *[01569](?: *\d)*) *$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bet7m1/1